# How to disable create a resource if it exists?

Tags: django, tastypie

I can create a `MessageResource` using post method, however, I want to return something like "message exists" if the `MessageResource` text has already in database. how to implement it? My `MessageResource` is

```
class MessageResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Message.objects.all()
        resource_name = "message"
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

        filtering = {
                'body': ALL
                }

    def determine_format(self, request):
        return "application/json"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
from tastypie.exceptions import BadRequest

class MessageResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Message.objects.all()
        resource_name = "message"
        always_return_data = True
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

        filtering = {
            'body': ALL
            }

    def determine_format(self, request):
        return "application/json"

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        if not bundle.obj.pk and len(Message.objects.filter(text=bundle.obj.text)) > 0:
            raise BadRequest('Message exists')
        return bundle
```

Or you can also use [validation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validation.html).